# Typescript: Why does Array.include(arg) flag the *possibility* that arg is not included?

Tags: typescript

Here's a sketch of my code:

```
const wordTypes = ['noun', 'verb', 'conjunction'] as const;
type TWordType = wordTypes[number];

const grammarTypes = ['pronunciation', 'etymology', ...wordTypes] as const;
type TGrammarType = grammarTypes[number];

// Later in my code:
const willReturnUnknownInAdvanceMemberOfGrammarTypes = ():TGrammarType => {...};
const test: TGrammarType = willReturnUnknownInAdvanceMemberOfGrammarTypes();

// Now I want to know if test is a member of wordTypes array
const isWord = wordTypes.includes(test); // !!!
```

The problem is that the line above marked `// !!!` gets flagged with the message:

```
Argument of type '"pronunciation" | "etymology" | "noun" | "verb" | "conjunction" is not assignable to parameter of type '"noun" | "verb" | "conjunction"'.
  Type 'etymology' is not assignable to type '"noun" | "verb" | "conjunction"'. ts(2345)
```

What the?! This seems ridiculous -- as though typescript is essentially saying that `test` *might* have a value such as not to be included in an array and, therefore, I must be in error; but isn't that the whole point of the `.includes()` method -- to test whether it is included or not?

Can someone please help me understand the motivation for this strange `tsc` behavior, and perhaps suggest a clean way to rearrange my types/logic to avoid this flag? Thanks!

Comment: Everyone knows: [ms/TS#26255](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26255)

Comment: Well, *now* everyone does